# matrix multiplication with numpy array object and dataframe

Tags: pandas, numpy, matrix

I did this using a for loop and feel like there is a faster way to achieve it but it eludes me.

```
datal=[[-9.8839112e-05, -0.001128727317, -0.000197679149],
 [-0.0009201639200000001, 0.0005601014289999999, 0.000496686232],
 [-0.000184700668, 9.414391600000001e-05, 0.000409526574]]

bigtranfo=[array([[ 0.89442732,  0.        ,  0.44721334],
        [ 0.44721334,  0.        , -0.89442732],
        [-0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ]]),
 array([[ 0.27639329,  0.85065091,  0.44721334],
        [ 0.13819655,  0.42532516, -0.89442732],
        [-0.9510565 ,  0.30901705,  0.        ]]),
 array([[-0.72360684,  0.52573128,  0.44721334],
        [-0.36180316,  0.26286545, -0.89442732],
        [-0.58778535, -0.80901692,  0.        ]])]

vectorfield=[]
    for i in range(0,3):
        x=list(bigtransfo[i].dot(datal[['tx','ty','tz']].iloc[i]))
        vectorfield.append(x)
    vf=pd.DataFrame(vectorfield,columns=['tx','ty','tz'])
```

**output:**
`[[-0.00017680915486414586, 0.00013260746120237444, -0.001128727317],
 [0.00044424836491567196, -0.0003331879850180065, 0.0010482087675674915],
 [0.000366290815094829, -0.00027471928608663234, 3.240032593749042e-05]]`

`bigtransfo` is an object containing 800 3x3 arrays, transformations. `datal` is just a chunk of a data frame that has 800 rows and three columns. The idea is to multiply the three components of each row, the selected vector, by the corresponding transformation.

Any ideas are welcome. Thanks in advance.

**update:** Added working example.

Comment: This `dot` converts the frame to an array before using it.  You'd get more help if you described the problem entirely with arrays.  Be clear about dimensions.  Better yet, provide a small working example, one that we can compare our improves to.

Comment: For 'batched' dots, `matmul` (`@`) and `np.einsum` are useful.

Comment: @hpaulj I added a small working example. Thanks for the sugesstion.